# Error changing HTML element's css class using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, class

I am getting an error when loading the page without any GET parameters (eg.: /login.php), here is the error I get:

```
 ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: err in          C:\wamp\www\GestionImagesPublicitesAvis\login.php on line 57
    Call Stack
    #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
     1  0.0005  144120  {main}( )   ..\login.php:0
```

And here is the code snippet from line 41 to line 58:

```
    <input class=
            <?php if(!empty($err))
                {
                    if($err == "up")
                    {
                        echo "\"InputError\"";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "\" \"";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "\" \"";
                } ?> 
            type="text" name="username" onclick="this.value='';" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'login...':this.value;" value=<?php if (($_GET['err'] == 'up')&& (isset($_GET['u']))){echo ("\"" . $_GET['u'] . "\"");}else{ echo "\"login...\"";} ?> id="username"/>
            <input class=<?php if($err=="up"){echo "\"InputError\"";}else{echo "\"\"";}?> type="password" name="password" onclick="this.value='';" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'motdepasse':this.value;" value="motdepasse" id="password"/>
```

$err is defined earlier in the page (line 15):`

```
<?php 
            $err;
                if (isset($_GET['err']))
                {
                    switch ($_GET['err'])
                    {
                    case "up":
                        $err = "up";
                        echo "<p>Error #156</p>";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $err=null;
                    echo "<p>Error #157</p>";
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: and what is your question? How to fix your notice?

Comment: $err doesn't have an initial value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top of the page (second code example) you only make sure `$err` is set and not `$_GET['err']`. Later on in line 57 (first code example), however, you again just use `$_GET['err']`.

Your error should be fixed, if you refer to `$err` in the code, after initializing it.

So your line 57 should similar to this:

```
type = "text" name="username" onclick="this.value='';" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'login...':this.value;" value=<?php if (($err == 'up')&& (isset($_GET['u']))){echo ("\"" . $_GET['u'] . "\"");}else{ echo "\"login...\"";} ?> id="username"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Too much coding, I'm almost blind when taking a look at my code and it seems like I start doing really stupid mistakes! Time to sleep a little bit. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
value=<?php if (($_GET['err'] == 'up')
```

You should do

```
value=<?php if ((@$_GET['err'] == 'up')
```

or

```
value=<?php if ((isset($_GET['err']) && $_GET['err'] == 'up')
```

Answer (score -1):

change your error_logging as $_GET['err'] will throw the Notice if err is not in the url.

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); or inside the php.ini

Comment: You're hiding the problem not fixing it tbh